# DNS issue - with just one site

Tags: hosting, domain-name-system

I still seem to always have issues with the DNS. I bought both domains on GoDaddy and both domain point to the same virtual host, one seems to work (neighborly), the other (brtest) doesn't resolve. Maybe you can help me make sense of this screenshot.

Is the DNS working but not the host? Is the DNS not pointed correctly?

[image: DNS Watch Screen Shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The authoritative name servers for the domain are ns1.netsonic.net and ns2.netsonic.net, and they're refusing requests for that domain name. Either your registrar is pointing at the wrong authoritative name servers, or your DNS provider has screwed up.

Comment: I still don't quite understand. Either the registrar (godaddy in this case - correct?) is pointing at the wrong authoritative name or the DNS provider has screwed up?

Who/what is the DNS provider?

Comment: The registrar is Godaddy, if that's who you registered the domain with. The DNS provider is whoever you have an arrangement with saying that they will run the authoritative name servers for your domain. It can be the registrar, it can be someone else, or it can be you.